# Why do different delivery methods have different results when applying PHP's global keyword?

Tags: php, scope, reference, garbage-collection, global

> PHP implements the static and global modifier for variables in terms of references. For example, a true global variable imported inside a function scope with the global statement actually creates a reference to the global variable. This can lead to unexpected behaviour which the following example addresses:
>
> ```
> <?php
> function test_global_ref() {
>     global $obj;
>     $new = new stdClass;
>     $obj =& $new;
> }
>
> function test_global_noref() {
>     global $obj;
>     $new = new stdClass;
>     $obj = $new;
> }
>
> test_global_ref();
> var_dump($obj);
> test_global_noref();
> var_dump($obj);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> NULL
> object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
> }
> ```

URL: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references

I found this example on the variable scope page of the PHP manual, but I don't understand why the first `var_dump` is null. I even output `$obj` in the `test_global_ref` function. `$obj` still has value, but why is it null when outputting `$obj` in the global scope?

Comment: Whatever you mean by "this example": can you share the code involved **in text form**?

Comment: Great examples for why both globals and references are usually not great ideas.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code sample, `$obj` is set as [a *reference*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to `$new`. When that function ends, `$new` is cleaned up (as it's no longer in scope for any actively running code), leaving the reference going nowhere.

In the second sample, `$obj` is set to `$new` *without* using a reference, so PHP knows to keep the value around.